# Pass Data from Partial View to Parent View

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a Profile page with a Postcode look up feature from https://postcodes.io. So far I have a Partial View with Ajax Form using the following code.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_CityLookUp", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "div1",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{
    <div id="div1">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PostCode, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.County, new { @class = "form-control", id = "County" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control", id = "City" })
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Look Up" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This works. I then rendered the Partial Page on the main profile page with the main profile form.

I just want to assign the value from the two other hidden fields to fields in the main page.

Partial Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult _CityLookUp()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult _CityLookUp(string postcode)
    {
        var client = new PostcodesIOClient();
        var result = client.Lookup(postcode);
        var jst = new AddressLookupViewModel();
        jst.City = result.AdminDistrict;
        jst.County = result.AdminCounty;
        jst.PostCode = postcode;
        ViewBag.City = jst.City;
        ViewBag.County = jst.County;

        var results = new BooksViewModel();
        results.City = jst.City;
        results.County = jst.County;

        return PartialView(jst);
    }
```

I have tried a new view model and assigning the results to the view model but it didn't work. Tried using JavaScript to get the value of the hidden field, no luck. If you'd rather do with a separate method, please explain how you would implement it.

Parent View

```
@model TestingView.Models.ParentViewModel
<div class="container">

    @Html.Partial("_CityLookUp")

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.City, new { @class = "form-control", id = "City" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PartialViewModel

```
namespace TestingView.Models
{
    public class AddressLookupViewModel
    {
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Parent View Model

```
namespace TestingView.Models
{
    public class ParentViewModel
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Side question: For some reason, when I hover over

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control", id = "City" })
```

on the parent view, it references the AddressLookUpViewModel and not the BooksViewModel in the parent view.. I have added both View Models.

Comment: What is your model declared with `@model` directive in parent view? Did that `postcode` parameter contains postal code string and getting any errors? At this moment I suspected you're not passing all necessary data from partial view to the POST partial view action, therefore viewmodel properties in parent view didn't updated.

Comment: It sounds like you want a single 'profile' form with some of the fields populated by an ajax helper.  Is that right?  If so, can you show the profile form view, its model and its controller?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto. I don't understand what you mean, I have added the ViewModels if that will give you a better picture.

Comment: @Khyron, Sure that would work also but i am not sure how to implement that. Also, I have added the parent view. Will i not need to use a partial View, please explain how i could implement this.

Comment: So the user types in a postcode, an ajax request fires and displays the relevant city and then there are some other fields the user can fill in.  Is that right?

Comment: With regards to the issue with `AddressLookUpViewModel`, try closing and reopening the view.  Visual Studio doesn't handle changes to @model declarations.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to simplify your question as much as possible.  It might help to appropriately name your view models here just to remove some confusion.

Comment: @Khyron Yes. That's essentially my goal. Again, sorry for the naming. If you wanna show me an example, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer this two ways; first using the approach you were initially asking about and then how I would prefer to implement this.

**Solution 1**

With this approach we will copy the value of the City element from the partial view to the parent view.

First thing we need to fix up is when you view the profile right now, there will be two elements with an Id of "City"; one from the parent page and one from the partial.  That's invalid markup and it will cause problems for any potential solution.

Rename the Id attribute in the parent view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(v => v.City, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Profile_City" })
```

Update the partial view to call a js function when it successfully retreives a set of postcode values:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_CityLookUp", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "div1",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    OnSuccess = "UpdateProfile" // Add this
}))
```

Add a js function, UpdateProfile, to the end of the parent view:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        function UpdateProfile()
        {
            var City = $("#City").val();
            alert(City);
            $("#Profile_City").val(City);
        }
    </script>
    }
```

That should be all that's required.  The alert is just there for debugging.

The `@section scripts` code will be injected in to your `_Layout.cshtml` where it calls `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`, part of the default MVC project.

One problem that might crop up going forward is when you build the parent view into a `form` you might be tempted to nest the form elements for layout reasons but nested form elements aren't permitted.

Comment: I will accept this answer cos it fixes my current code. Not to take away from the other answer as that works as well!!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 2**

This approach uses `jQuery's ajax()` method to fetch the data and directly populate the relevant fields on a form.

Set up the model.

```
namespace TestingView.Models
{
    public class ProfileViewModel
    {
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is a copy of `AddressLookupViewModel` as it contains all the necessary fields.  I have simply renamed it to suggest its use is for the main profile form itself.

Create the view.

The view now has a single `Html.BeingForm()`, with the Look Up button bound to an ajax function rather than submitting an ajax form.

Its not 100% clear to me whether you want the user to be able to edit the County and City fields after a look up.  In the code below they can.

```
@model TestingView.Models.ProfileViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PostCode, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Lookup()">Look Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.County, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.County, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section scripts {
    <script>
        function Lookup() {
            $.ajax("/Home/CityLookup", {
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    postcode: $("#PostCode").val()
                }
            })
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log("Success");
                console.log(response);
                var cityObj = response;
                $("#City").val(cityObj.City);
                console.log("City " + cityObj.City);
                $("#County").val(cityObj.County);
            })
            .error(function () {
                alert("There was a problem looking up the postcode");
            })
        };
    </script>
    }
```

Create a controller to service the ajax request.  This is heavily based on your `POST _CityLookUp` controller.  Note the Action type is `JsonResult` and the return converts the `jst` object in to a JSON string.  Using JSON makes the lookup extensible; we can return multiple properties as an object and unpack them to a javascript object for use client-side.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CityLookup(string postcode)
{
    var client = new PostcodesIOClient();
    var result = client.Lookup(postcode);
    var jst = new AddressLookupViewModel();
    jst.City = result.AdminDistrict;
    jst.County = result.AdminCounty;
    jst.PostCode = postcode;
    return Json(jst);
}
```